# the viewcontroller does not respect the constraints (xamarin.ios)

Tags: xamarin, layout, xamarin.ios, constraints

I was trying a slide transaction on xamarin.ios where the vc2 (the one initialized in the code) flows over the vc1 (the previous one) and is full-screen, however in my code the vc1 interpenetrates with the constraints that are not respected when the animation ends, resulting in this way ..

[image]

while the result should be this ..

[image]

now I have been trying to solve it case for a while, I ran out of solutions and I still don't understand why it looks like that, the code is this ..

```
public void SlideTo(UIView View, string A)
    {
        var CC = CGAffineTransform.MakeTranslation(View.Bounds.Size.Width, 0);
        var DD = CGAffineTransform.MakeTranslation(0, 0);

        //Istanzio il vc
        var storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);
        var vc = storyboard.InstantiateViewController(A);
        
        CALayer gradient = new CALayer();
        gradient.Frame = vc.View.Bounds;
        vc.View.Layer.InsertSublayer(gradient, 1);
        View.AddSubview(vc.View);

        //Centro quella giusta
        vc.View.Transform = true ? CC : DD;

        UIView.Animate(1, 0, UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, () =>
        {
            vc.View.Transform = true ? DD : CC;


        }, null);
    }
```

please only solutions for xamarin.ios (not swift)

Comment: Hi , do you mean that layout shows correctly with icon in each item ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safe area is a new way of thinking about the visible space of your application and how constraints are added between a view and a super view.

Maybe this problem is result from `SafeArea`.

Here you can modify code as follow to have a try :

```
public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewDidAppear(animated);
    
    //suberView is your table view 
    View.Add(suberView);
    suberView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

    var safeGuide = View.SafeAreaLayoutGuide;
    suberView.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(safeGuide.LeadingAnchor).Active = true;
    suberView.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(safeGuide.TrailingAnchor).Active = true;
    suberView.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(safeGuide.TopAnchor).Active = true;
    suberView.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(safeGuide.BottomAnchor).Active = true;

    View.LayoutIfNeeded();
}
```

Comment: love you, thank you very much I solved! I have not used the viewdidappear method because the problem was on a delegate but it works the same way <3 thanks again!

Comment: @AlessandroLedda Gald solved that ! You are welcome :-)

Comment: @AlessandroLedda If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue. :-)

Comment: i'm sorry, I don't know the platform well yet, I did it now as you suggested!